# Implementing A Sort Using 3 Stacks. (Segmentation Fault - Core Dump)

Tags: c++

I'm getting a Segmentation Fault - Core Dump during runtime.
 I'm trying to figure out how to get rid of the Segmentation Fault.
 It's a class homework.
 EDIT: Added Input and Output below.

```
//client.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "stack.h"

using namespace std;

int main(void){
    stack unsorted;
    stack stack1;
    stack stack2;
    stack stack3;
    int const MAX_VALUES = 5;
    int input;

    cout << "Please input "<< MAX_VALUES << " unique integers.\n";
    cout << "Click the ENTER key after each integer inputted." <<endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_VALUES; i++)
    {
        cin >> input;
        stack1.Push(input);
        unsorted.Push(input);
    }

    cout << "Unsorted Stack: " <<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_VALUES; i++)
    {
        cout<<unsorted.Pop()<<endl;

    }

    cout << "Sorted Stack: "<<endl;


    while((!stack1.IsEmpty())&&(!stack3.IsEmpty())){
        if ((stack1.IsEmpty())&&(!stack3.IsEmpty()))
        {
            stack2.Push(stack3.Pop());
        }
        if (stack2.Top() > stack1.Top())
        {
            stack3.Push(stack2.Pop());
        }
        if (stack3.Top() < stack1.Top())
        {
            stack2.Push(stack3.Pop());
        }
        else
        {
            stack2.Push(stack1.Pop());
        }
    }

    while (!stack2.IsEmpty()){
        cout << stack2.Pop() << endl;
    }

}

//stack.h

#include <cstddef>

struct node;

class stack
{
public:
    stack();   
    ~stack();  

    bool IsFull();
    bool IsEmpty();
    void Push(int input);
    int Pop();
    int Top();

private:
    node* top;
    int const MAX_VALUES = 5;
    int count;
};

//stack.cpp

#include "stack.h"

struct node
{
    int input;
    node* next;
};

stack::stack()
{
    top = NULL;
    count = 0;
}

bool stack::IsFull()
{
    if (MAX_VALUES > count)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
bool stack::IsEmpty(){
    if (top == NULL){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

void stack::Push(int num)
{
    if(IsFull() == false)
    {
        node* newNode = new node;
        newNode->input = num;
        newNode->next = top;
        top = newNode;
        count ++;
    }
}

int stack::Top()
{
    int topval;
    topval = top->input;    
    return topval;
}

int stack::Pop()
{
    int Popped;
    if (top != NULL)
    {
        node* temp = top;
        top = top->next;
        Popped = temp->input;
        delete temp;
        return Popped;
    }
    count--;
}


stack::~stack()
{
    node* current = top;

    while( top != NULL)
    {
        node* next = current->next;
        delete current;
        current = next;
    }
    top = NULL;
}
```

Input: 
Please input 5 unique integers.
Click the ENTER key after each integer inputted.
7
1
56
67
8

Output:

Unsorted Stack: 
8
67
56
1
7
Sorted Stack: 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Have you used a debugger to see where the crash is?

Comment: No I haven't, honestly, I've never used one. I've always self debugged. I'm a college sophomore. I write my c++ in sublime text, and then compile using g++ via the terminal. You have any idea a good one I can use ?

Comment: Pop doesn't return a value for all code paths and `while(top != NULL)` is the wrong condition in your destructor.  You want to check `current`.  Correcting those issues will make your program not crash, but it is still not correct.  You should learn to use a debugger.  If you're using g++ then you'll want to use gdb or a visual front end for gdb.

Comment: Thank You. @Molbdnilo was able to expand on what you wrote, and I got it working just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems.

First, your `Pop`:

```
int stack::Pop()
{
    int Popped;
    if (top != NULL)
    {
        node* temp = top;
        top = top->next;
        Popped = temp->input;
        delete temp;
        return Popped;
    }
    count--;
}
```

which decrements `count` *only* when the stack is empty, but doesn't return anything if it is.
You need something more like this:

```
int stack::Pop()
{
    int Popped = -1; // Make sure the return value is well-defined
    if (!IsEmpty())
    {
        node* temp = top;
        top = top->next;
        Popped = temp->input;
        delete temp;
        count--;   // Only decrement if we actually popped something.
    }
    return Popped;
}
```

and the destructor:

```
stack::~stack()
{
    node* current = top;

    while( top != NULL)
    {
        node* next = current->next;
        delete current;
        current = next;
    }
    top = NULL;
}
```

The loop will never stop because you have the wrong termination condition - unless the stack is empty, `top` will never become `NULL`.
It should be

```
stack::~stack()
{
    node* current = top;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        node* next = current->next;
        delete current;
        current = next;
    }
    top = NULL;
}
```

And the loop in `main` starts like this (I've removed some unnecessary parentheses):

```
while (!stack1.IsEmpty() && !stack3.IsEmpty()) {
    if (stack1.IsEmpty() && !stack3.IsEmpty())
```

where the `if` condition will never be true if the `while` condition is - `stack1` can't be both empty and not empty.

Side note: having a size limit when you implement a stack as a linked list is a bit odd.